# Convert multiple bsq files to jpg images in python

Tags: python, gdal, jpg

I am trying to convert a big number of bsq files to JPEG images. I found the way to do it only for one file but I cannot figure out how to put it in a loop in order to run repetitively all the files that are in a folder. Here is what I already did because I have already found it online.

```
import gdal

img_bsq  =image.bsq
img_jpg  =image.jpg

gdal.Translate(img_jpg, img_bsq, format='JPEG', width=1024, height=0, 
scaleParams=[[]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do this in Python but a simply batch or bash script that calls `GDAL_TRANSLATE` for each bsb will do the trick.

`set /p bsbfolder=folder` where NOAA RNC are located:

`for /r "%bsbfolder%" %%f in (*.kap) do gdal_translate -of JPEG -co WORLDFILE=YES -co QUALITY 75 %%f %%~nf.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for you reply but actually what you are suggesting it does not work. I just gives a black and white image and this is not actually how it should look like.

Comment: -expand gray|rgb|rgba:
(From GDAL 1.6.0) To expose a dataset with 1 band with a color table as a dataset with 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA) bands. Useful for output drivers such as JPEG, JPEG2000, MrSID, ECW that don't support color indexed datasets. The 'gray' value (from GDAL 1.7.0) enables to expand a dataset with a color table that only contains gray levels to a gray indexed dataset.

Comment: Loop technique should work, but issue I assume is confusion between BSB, and BSQ formats

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you iterate over all the files in a directory using Python. Note the importance of using the `os` module to manipulate file paths.

```
import gdal
import glob, os

in_ws = '/path/to/your/in_workspace'
out_ws = '/path/to/your/out_workspace'

# List bsq files in workspace
imgs = glob.glob(os.path.join(in_ws, "*.bsq"))

for img in imgs:
    # Define the output path
    out_jpg = os.path.join(out_ws, os.path.basename(img).split(".")[0] + ".jpg")
    
    # Convert to JPEG
    gdal.Translate(out_jpg, img, format='JPEG', width=1024, height=0, 
    scaleParams=[[]])
```